# rails actionmailer multiple recepients

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In my Rails app I want to use ActionMailer to send emails to multiple recipients.  Below is the code I've written that works with a single attribute:

```
 def new_call(medic, call)
    @call = call
    @medic = medic

    mail to: @medic.medic_email, subject: "New Call: #{@call.incident_number}"
  end
```

I want to include @medic.medic_sms to send the message to their phones.  I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
 def new_call(medic, call)
    @call = call
    @medic = medic

    mail to: @medic.medic_email, @medic.medic_sms, subject: "New Call: #{@call.incident_number}"
  end
```

Can someone suggest how to add the second attribute cleanly so it works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the two attributes into an array solved the problem.

[@medic.medic_email, @medic.medic_sms]

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. If you want to pass an array to `to:`, you need to explicitly wrap it in `[]`:

```
mail to: [@medic.medic_email, @medic.medic_sms], subject: ...
```

See [ActionMailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) section [2.3.4: Sending Email To Multiple Recipients](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-to-multiple-recipients).